# Проблема с декодированием quoted-printable

Tags: c#, email, imap

При декодировании заголовка email-сообщения возникла проблема. Если кодировка - quoted-printable, закодированные символы переводятся в знаки вопроса. Например, `=D1=80=D0=B5=D1=82=D0=B2=D0=B8=D1=82=D0=BD=D1=83=D0=BB(=D0=B0)` вместо `ретвитнул(а)` переводит в `??????????????????(??)`, причём декодер Base64 отображает все символы корректно.

```
public static string DecodeEncodedLine(string text)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s*=\?(?<charset>.*?)\?(?<encoding>[qQbB])\?(?<value>.*?)\?=");
    string encoded = text;
    string decoded = string.Empty;

    while (encoded.Length > 0)
    {
        Match match = regex.Match(encoded);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            decoded += encoded.Substring(0, match.Index);
            string charset = match.Groups["charset"].Value;
            string encoding = match.Groups["encoding"].Value.ToUpper();
            string value = match.Groups["value"].Value;

            if (encoding.Equals("B"))
            {
                var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
                decoded += Encoding.GetEncoding(charset).GetString(bytes);
            }
            else if (encoding.Equals("Q"))
            {

                Regex reg = new Regex(@"(\=([0-9A-F][0-9A-F]))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                decoded += reg.Replace(value, new MatchEvaluator(m =>
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[m.Value.Length / 3];
                    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
                    {
                        string hex = m.Value.Substring(i * 3 + 1, 2);
                        int iHex = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
                        bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(iHex);
                    }
                    return Encoding.GetEncoding(charset).GetString(bytes);
                })).Replace('_', ' ');
            }
            else
            {
                decoded += encoded;
                break;
            }

            encoded = encoded.Substring(match.Index + match.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            decoded += encoded;
            break;
        }
    }
    return decoded;
}
```

Также пробовал `Attachment attachment = Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString("", stringAttached);` - результат тот же.

Comment: У вас неправильная кодировка. Похоже что должен быть UTF-8, то вы декодируете в ASCII

Comment: и как это исправить?

Comment: `Encoding.GetEncoding(charset)`, но я не знаю, откуда должен браться charset если он явно не указан в строке

Comment: `=?UTF-8?Q?=D1=80=D0=B5`, строка имеет такой формат

Comment: Посмотрите в отладчике какая там кодировка создается, или я должен сделать это за вас?

Comment: utf-8, проверено 200000 раз перед тем, как задать вопрос

Comment: Сори, понял в чем ваша ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы декодируете байты по-одному, а нужно декодировать группами. Вот исправленный код для quoted-printable:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(\=(?<byte>[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]))+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
decoded += reg.Replace(value, new MatchEvaluator(m =>
{
    byte[] bytes = m.Groups["byte"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(c => (byte)Convert.ToInt32(c.Value, 16)).ToArray();
    return Encoding.GetEncoding(charset).GetString(bytes);
})).Replace('_', ' ');
```